# How to pass data to fancybox function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, argument-passing

I have wrote following code:

html:

```
 <a class="fancybox" caption="This is 1st title" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" data-page1 alt=""/></a>


 <a class="fancybox" caption="This is 2nd title" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" data-page2 alt=""/></a>
```

js:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .fancybox({
         beforeLoad: function () {
             alert(this);
              this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
    }
});
```

I want to show text taken from data attribute before image will show(page1 or page2).

Please, help to modify me code.

http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/25/

Comment: where do you want to show this text? as an alert?

Comment: do you mean data-caption= "my text" and then $...,attr("data-caption") ?

Comment: I think you want to show the text in the center before the images gets loaded am I right?

Comment: @CodeGodie yeah, in alert

Comment: Actually I don't understand how to pass data to function

Comment: why do you call your attribute `caption`? is there a reason why? you usually would call it `title` or `data-title` or `data-caption` not just  `caption`

Comment: You're alerting an object! Simply move the alert() to be AFTER where you set `this.title` and then, `alert(this.title);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
<a class="fancybox" caption="This is 1st title" 
href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
    <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" data-page="1" alt=""/> 
</a>
```

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    console.log(this.element.find('img').data('page')); 
    console.log(this.element.attr('caption'));
    // etc...
}
```

The element is already a jQuery object, so no need to pass it in to the jQuery function. Also, I suggest that you use either html5 data attributes or valid property names i.e. not "caption".

http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/27/

Answer (score 0):

Want to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/30/

```
alert($(this.element).attr('caption'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like youre calling (alerting) the `this` object. You need to use the `title` attribute like this: **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9GwUu/31/)**